# How to Invoke method with an exact annotation name without traversing the Method[] Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I need to invoke an exact annotated method using Java reflection. I know I can traverse all the `Method[]` and check the annotations. But is there a straight way to do this without traversing the `Method[]` ? Is `java.lang.reflect` support this or do I need to use an external library for this ?

Comment: Traversing an array of methods is going to happen either in your code or in the library code, but there would be a full scan of all methods. We are talking about five to ten lines of custom code here.

Answer (score 0):

An array iteration is going to happen regardless of whether it is in your code or in a library.

If you don't mind the dependency, [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) has a nice way to do this:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<Method> resources = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(javax.ws.rs.Path.class);
```

If you just need the one method you can just pull the first index of the resulting `Set`.